# Effectively release unmanaged resources when process is killed

Tags: c#, windows, mmap, memory-mapped-files, unmanagedresources

I have multiple processes (or rather multiple instances of a process) trying to (create or) access a single memory-mapped-file. I'm using Mutex to synchronize (first) creation of mmap file.

When all the processes run the first time, it works well and data is read properly. But if I close all the processes (as they take a long time) by 'right click -> close all windows' and start the processes again immediately, I face issues like System.IO.IOException: Pipe is broken. The unmanaged resources are not cleaned properly in time. I'm using dispose() method towards the end of the program.

```
MemoryMappedFile mmf;
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, mmapName.Substring(2));
mutex.WaitOne();
try
{  
    mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(mmapName);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(rFile, FileMode.Open, mmapName);
}
mutex.ReleaseMutex();
MemoryMappedViewStream fileStream = mmf.CreateViewStream(0, 0, 
MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read);
...
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue? 'using' keyword wouldn't help. Should I use SafeHandles? (I'm not experienced with SafeHandles but there are some SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle / SafeMemoryMappedViewHandles already provided.)

Comment: Is this a WPF Desktop app? Hitting Close all windows doesn't always terminate your application if there are still working threads. Verify in task manager that the process is killed when you close window. Also, please clarify what you mean by saying using keyword isn't working.

Comment: These are console applications. 'using' keyword to automatically clean resources is not helpful as the process is killed in between the operations.

Comment: Also, the processes are killed immediately (verified from process explorer) but probably the memory mapped file is not cleaned up yet and new processes are requesting the same mmap file (with same name).